# Inno setup scripting error

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

hi everyone this is my first time using inno setup and im slowly getting the hang of it but im still a noob hahaha anyway im having problems

when i get all my files togethere installing everything is fine but when i run my app it doesnt work properly

example when installing msys2 on my pc and im adding all my files including msys i run it but it gives me problems

no error http://www.mediafire.com/view/qv480u858f8888x/no%20errors%20running%20msys.png

after using inno setup http://www.mediafire.com/view/c8ifah5hl61mian/using%20inno%20setup.png

i can use it properly the inno setup one if i run as admin but i dont want to do that hopefully i explained enough information

i dont want to run i t as admin i want to run it normal like you would see in the first folder if i add admin then i cant drag or drop files if its admin so no admin but errors with inno setup

Comment: How does your added comment *"want to run it normal"* change the question? You already told us that before. And actually the very fact, that you cannot run the application unless in the admin mode, is **the indication**, that you have the same problem as addressed in my answer to the linked question.

Comment: i dont t\see that the link you showed doesnt help my question anyway

Comment: So that you will have to try harder to explain your problem.

Comment: If you copy your application files manually to the same folder, where Inno Setup installs them, does your application work correctly?

Comment: well it runs corrently if i run the application as admin like right click admin but if i just run normal i get that error it the photos aboves

Comment: So you get the same problem, even if you "install/deploy" the app manually without Inno Setup?

Comment: the app runs like normal without inno setup like open it normal and i dont have to run as admin like in the first one but after using inno setup i get the error but if i run as admin its fine but i dont want it like that coz i cant drag or drop file or folder in the app once its admin

Comment: Sorry, but you keep being vague. To what directory do you install the app using Inno Setup? + What does it mean *"after using inno setup i get the error"*? Do you mean that you get the problem for the installed application only? Or even for uninstalled application?

Comment: i just install it to programs folder and after i installed it is where it get errors

Comment: If you copy the app manually to "program folder", does it work?

Comment: from app that was made by inno setup so lick right 7zip inside of it or

Comment: Sorry, but that's not a sentence. + I'm not asking about *"app that was made by inno setup"*. I'm asking about *your application*.

Comment: yes it runs fine

Comment: So what's different between the folder created by Inno Setup and the folder created by you manually?

Comment: i cant run app made with inno setup unless admin my normal app runs fine with running as admin

Comment: That's now what I have asked. If the application runs fine, if you copy it manually to "program folder". But does not run correctly, if Inno Setup copies it to "program folder", there must be some difference in a file structure or permissions of files/folders. What is the difference? Did you check?